# Наличие/отсутствие запятой перед КАК

Tags: пунктуация, как

**Это праздник, которого с нетерпением ждут дети и взрослые. Ждут (,) как настоящего чуда, которое подарит самые счастливые минуты и светлые надежды.**

Стоит не выдумывать и ставить запятую или здесь имеется какая-нибудь тесная связь со сказуемым? Или что-то другое? *(Конец рабочего дня в конце года – тяжёлое время, соображалка соображает всё хуже, к сожалению.)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Это праздник, которого с нетерпением ждут дети и взрослые. **Ждут как настоящего чуда,** которое подарит самые счастливые минуты и светлые надежды.

Сравнить: Ждут **праздника**, как настоящего **чуда**, которое подарит самые счастливые минуты и светлые надежды.

2) **Пояснение**

Нет повтора, характерного для сравнения (праздника, как чуда), поэтому нет паузы, ударение переносится на оборот: ждут (как)настоящего чУда.

3) **И еще:** придаточное относится к обороту (чудо, которОЕ подарит), как-то стиль не выдержан.

В качестве варианта: Ждут как настоящего чуда, с которым связывают самые счастливые минуты и светлые надежды

Answer (score 2):

На мой взгляд, тут два варианта постановки запятых:

1. Сравнительный оборот (ждут, словно чуда), запятая ставится:

> Это праздник, которого с нетерпением ждут дети и взрослые. Ждут, как настоящего чуда, которое подарит самые счастливые минуты и светлые надежды.

2. Тесная связь со сказуемым (ждут как чуда), запятая не ставится:

> Это праздник, которого с нетерпением ждут дети и взрослые. Ждут как настоящего чуда, которое подарит самые счастливые минуты и светлые надежды.

Думаю, тут будет уместно и авторское тире (хотя это контекстуально):

> Это праздник, которого с нетерпением ждут дети и взрослые. Ждут — как настоящего чуда, которое подарит самые счастливые минуты и светлые надежды.

Насчет управления глагола *ждать*:

> ЖДАТЬ — 1. чего (при сочетании с отвлеченным существительным или конкретным, но **употребленным с оттенком неопределенности**). Ждать возможности; Ждать писем; Ждать поезда (какого-л.); Я ждал только случая, чтобы показать ему, что нисколько не дорожу его обществом (Л. Т.).
>   2. кого-что (при сочетании с одушевленным существительным или неодушевленным, но употребленным с оттенком определенности). Ждать сестру; Я жду одну женщину (Т.); Ждать ежедневную почту; Ждать поезд Симферополь—Москва.
>
> *Управление в русском языке
>
>   Автор Д. Э. Розенталь.*

Comment: 1. Разделяю эту точку зрения 2. В Нацкорпусе нашел только один подходящий пример, и в нем нет запятой: *Однако этой свободы мы ждём как внезапного чуда, которое без наших усилий вдруг выпадет нам, сами же ничего не делаем для завоевания той свободы. [А. И. Солженицын. Образованщина // «Новый мир», 1974]*

Comment: @М_Г К запятым в Нацкорпусе надо относиться с осторожностью, потому что выверять пунктуацию не в его целях. Тем не менее, примеры заслуживают внимания!